# How to use ISBLANK in nested if-statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, excel-formula

I need help in converting the following if-statements in Excel formula.

- if A1 and B1 are blank, then C1 is "",
- if A1 is not blank and B1 is blank, then C1 is "New",
- if A1 and B1 are not blank, then C1 is "Existing".

Here is what I have could have tried but didn't bother to:

```
IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),ISBLANK(B1)),"NEW",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),(NOT(ISBLANK(‌​B1)),"EXISTING",""))
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: What have you tried? And [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634204.aspx) if you want to know how to use ISBLANK.

Comment: Hi, I tried this formula but I'm having error  IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"", IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),ISBLANK(B1)),"NEW",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),"EXISTING",""))

Answer (score 1):

Check the below formula and hope this will help you.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"New",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),NOT(ISBLANK(B1))),"Existing")))
```

Put this formula in C1 and try to check...

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",IF(ISBLANK(B1),"New","Existing"))
```

("ignores" that `A1` may be blank unless `B1` is also).

Answer (score 1):

Code golf!

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","New"),"Existing")

=IF(ISBLANK(A1)=ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","Existing"),"New")
```

Note that as your question is stated, behaviour is undefined for blank A1 and non-blank B1. For such input, the first formula will give "Existing" and the second one "New".

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but blank isn't the same as empty string! So if A1 and B1 contain e.g. `=""` they're not technically blank, so the output should be `Existing` but it will be `""` with your formula.